# How to merge a swap (.swp) file to the original file?

Tags: files, filesystem, swap

I was running a program from bash with its output redirected to a file (test.out). The process died due to some issues (the issues are not important in this context) and now I am left with two files:

- The original output file `test.out` which is 2.1 GB, and
- The swap file generated `.test.out.swp` which is 19 MB

Is there a way to merge these files, as in appending the swap file at the end of the original file?

Or, am I wrong in wanting to do this? Does the swap file have a different purpose than being used with output/log?

Comment: Was the `.swp` file created by Vim?

Comment: I would agree with muru; the .swp file is probably a working file used by a program (i see it regularly with vi/vim/..) & *probably* not part of output you're after

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vim uses .swp files as storage areas for unfinished work, allowing it to edit very large files even if they can't fit completely in memory.  This is a legacy from the times when computer RAM was very small and large files that didn't fit in memory was more common, but it has remained, and means we can edit files that are many Gigabytes without eating up all available RAM or killing processes.  Vim deletes the .swp file when it has finished editing, or leaves it if the process exits abnormally.

If you have a .swp file and an original file, you *can* somewhat recover lost work.  This is documented here:

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/recover.html

To recover a file, simply open the original file.  vim will notice that there is already a .swp file associated with the file and will give you a warning and ask what you want to do.  Assuming you have the required privileges to write to the file, "recover" should be one of the options given.

Alternatively you may start a new vim instance (on a blank document) and use the command `:recover <file>` stating the file you want to recover.

Note that the primary use for .swp files is as temporary storage for vim enabling it to edit large files, NOT recovery.  As such vim doesn't journal writes to the file, and if power is lost during editing the .swp file may become corrupt.  Fortunately the recover tool in vim is fairly tolerant to partially corrupt .swp files and will still attempt to recover as much of the lost changes to the file as it can.  Look for the existence of three question marks: `???` in the recovered file, as these will be inserted whenever corruption was found in the .swp file.

Once you are happy with the recovery you need to manually delete the .swp file to ensure you don't keep getting the warning when you go to edit the file.  Be careful not to run the recovery process a second time.

Answer (score 1):

### Direct answer

To technically answer your question:

```
cat test.out > experiment.out
cat .test.out.swp >> experiment.out
```

The first redirection of the `cat` command `>` creates a new file. The second redirection of the `cat` command `>>` appends to the existing file.

In reality `experiment.out` probably won't be usable because you are adding an apple to an orange.

---

### Alternative Repair

You can google repairing the files: [Superuser.com How can I recover the original file from a .swpfile?](https://superuser.com/questions/204209/how-can-i-recover-the-original-file-from-a-swp-file?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) In short use:

```
vim -r .swp
```

**Make copies of all files first!**

If that doesn't work I'd use `gedit` on both files in separate tabs and then in a third tab paste text copied from the first two tabs.